# Clear All Contents of Word FIle Apache POI

Tags: file, ms-word, apache-poi

I am using Apache POI to write on an already created word document, before I want to write to the document (If I run the program again) I want to clear all of the contents of a document.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I used FileUtils.copyFile() to copy the template after deleting the old file from Apache Commons, thanks for the answer though.